# zabbix 2.2.1 no graphs in Web scenario

Tags: zabbix

Hello  for some time I have a problem with graphs in web scenarios on Zabbix 2.2.1, I put below the screen, this problem has appeared at every graph of web scenario

[image]

This same scenario installed a second zabbixie that runs on my local virtual machine with zabbix. In my local machine all components of zabbix (server, frontend, agents), but in my production zabbix only zabbix frontend are separated from each other.

```
 Scenario for openerp
 ==============================

 Name: OpenERP Web Checks

 Application: 

 New application: 

 Authentication: 

 Update interval (in sec): 60

 Retries: 1

 Agent: Internet Explorer 10.0


 Steps:
 ==============================
 Name: OpenERP login page

 URL: http://openerp.test.com

 Post: 

 Variables: 

 Timeout: 15

 Required string: 

 Required status codes: 200
```

My zabbix server performance:

[image]
Anybody have some idea how fix it ?

Regards
Mick

Comment: Could you please show Web scenario configuration (in particular, what is its update interval) and how busy your HTTP pollers are (obtainable using "zabbix[process,http poller,avg,busy]" internal check)?

Comment: Zabbix busy http poller processes, in %  | 27 May 2014 10:28:39 | 100 %  -

Answer (score 1):

If the HTTP Pollers is 100% busy, which mean it cannot run your web scenario smoothly
You may add additional HTTP Pollers to solve this:

1. Go to zabbix_server.conf
2. Edit StartHTTPPollers=(Thread count)
3. Restart Zabbix server

In result, you may find the HTTP poller status using "ps" if you are using Linux